# Spock: How to input string values in a data pipe

Tags: testing, groovy, automation, spock, geb

I googled a lot but did not find a single example of populating input data with string values in a data pipe.

Can someone give an example of how to do it?

I used:

```
[a,b,c] << ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

but getting error.

Comment: Is this the error you get? `'leftShift' in 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods' cannot be applied to '([[java.lang.String, java.lang.String,...]])' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to run the test 3 times, with the same variable assigned "aaa" for the first run, "bbb" for the second, and "ccc" for the third, you you would do it like this:

```
where:
variableName << ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

Here's a complete example from one of my projects:

```
class PhoneNumberConverterSpec extends Specification {

    private PhoneNumberConverter phoneNumberConverter = PhoneNumberConverter.instance

    @Unroll('convert invalid phone number #input')
    def 'attempt to convert invalid phone numbers to canonical format'() {

        expect:
        !phoneNumberConverter.canConvert(input)

        where:
        input << [null, 6, '353', '9999999']
    }
}
```

If on the other hand, you want to run the test only once and assign values to 3 different variables then there's really no point in using data pipes, just declare and assign the variables as you would in regular Groovy code.

Comment: "there's really no point in using" == "it's not possible to use" ?

Comment: @cellepo no, you could use a data pipe if there's just a single set of values, but it's completely pointless and unnecessarily verbose

Comment: unless I misunderstand (I've been know to), I'm thinking it could be the _least_ verbose, as 1-liner `a, b, c << [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]`; instead of 3 (or n) lines `a = "aaa";\n` `b = "bbb";\n` `c = "ccc";\n`; or at least 2 lines with a data table.  But I haven't got data pipe with String[] array (specifically) to work yet; I can get it to work with an array that's not all Strings though

Comment: @cellepo I don't think the one-liner is any more concise than the 3-line version. More importantly, it's confusing because I wouldn't expect a data pipe to be used for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign multiple values to multiple variables is done like this:

```
def (a, b, c) = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

But input data for Spock like this would be more like this:

```
where:
a << [3, 7, 0]
b << [5, 0, 0]
c << [5, 7, 0]
```

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html